# Rig Weight Paint double paint

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, mirror

I have a problem with my weight painting. Here is the topo when painting my bones I find myself painting them on another bone at the same time and impossible to pass the bar of .5 point influence on the right side.

Let me show you[image]

Here you can see the paint weight I have on the `bicept.L`

[image]

And now I paint it at the max power I can so I can't go further than the green (it's  0.5 if it's correct) and the `Bicept.R` take is color too.

[image]

So I already remove the topology Mirror in the options but the mirror weight paint doesn't work after this, so I was wondering what I going wrong.

Also my radius disappearing so if someone can help me whit all my problems

Comment: Which Blender version is this?

Comment: v.2.90.1 do i need to uppgrade ?

Comment: Yes, the early 2.9 version had some issues/bugs with symmetry and weight painting. In 2.92 there is now an option named *Vertex Group X* under *Symmetry* which does the mirroring if you named the vertex groups/bones properly (such as *bone.L* or *bones.left.001*).

Comment: A simple workaround, to get rid of glitches with mirroring weight paint is: delete bicept.r, rename bicept.l as simply bicept, create a copy of bicept, use the "mirror vertex group" function on the copy, rename as needed.

Comment: ok, i will try to update blender and do what i have to correct this. and i have this probleme to all my bones not only the bicept

Comment: So, i've upgraded blender and delete renamme the bones and do a shift+D to duplicate them because the symmetrize didn't work ether, still have the same probleme even worst. However, how could we reset the parameters to zero need to see if it work

Comment: i re uploaded an ancient mesh, visibly the probleme is my mesh, what could be wrong ?

Comment: Where is the uploaded ancient mesh?

Comment: on my computer why ???

Comment: ok so I deleted half of my Mesh because it annoys me too much (I had no more ideas in mind) and obviously the painting works fine (finally) but as I have a mirror on my mesh it does not not going to cause problems for later?